# R scatterplot ylim error NA values

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am trying to recreate a graph I made in excel into R. Here is the excel version of the graph...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GjYd.png

My data set that is split into 5 segments. For simplicity, I am going to refer to my x and y labels as time and distance. I have 5 "cars" that I want to plot on the shape chart.

The CSV file with the data looks like this (not the real numbers!):

```
A       B       C      D      E      F     ...
1       4       1      8      7      15
3       5       5      10     12     20
5       6       7      14     20     40
```

where (A, B) gives you time/distance of car 1, (C, D) gives you time/distance of car 2 and (E, F) gives you time/distance of car 3 and so forth.

My code looks like this:

```
speed = read.csv (file = "c:/users/XXX/desktop/speed", header = TRUE, sep = ',')
plot (A ~ B, data = speed, xlim = range (1e-5:100), ylim = range (0:200), log = "x")     
par(new = TRUE) 
plot (C ~ D, data = speed, xlim = range (1e-5:100), ylim = range (0:200), log = "x") 
par (new = TRUE)
plot (E ~ F, data = speed, xlim = range (1e-5:100), ylim = range (0:200), log = "x") 
par(new = TRUE )
plot(G ~ H, data = speed, xlim = range (1e-5:100), ylim = range (0:200), log = "x") 
par (new = TRUE) 
plot(I ~ J, data = speed, xlim = range (1e-5:100), ylim = range (0:200), log = "x")
```

I get an error saying that I have an invalid ylim value... I tried changing the numbers and no luck.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Here is `dput(speed)` if it is helpful to anyone...
- I noticed the NA values in the dput, I think it comes from the fact that not every data set for each "car" is not equal? Not sure how to fix this...I could put each data set for each "car" into a different file, would that be better?

```
structure(list(A = c(3.59e-05, 3.75e-05, 9.67e-05, 3.92e-05, 
2.14e-05, 9.8e-05, 0.000228481, 0.000228481, 0.000415583, 0.000859052, 
0.002014948, 0.004079371, 0.00406138, 0.004353728, 0.008455587, 
0.007780939, 0.018260469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(4.76, 
6.28, 10.5, 10.6, 12.3, 12.8, 16, 16.8, 20.7, 25.2, 34.4, 36.4, 
37.7, 43.6, 48.7, 49.2, 66.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C = c(1.734691244, 
2.016976959, 1.707373272, 1.461511521, 0.805880184, 0.417509677, 
0.427070968, 0.220364977, 0.21763318, 0.170282028, 0.169826728, 
0.095612903, 0.094247005, 0.048717051, 0.044072995, 0.034921475, 
0.023721106, 0.022901567, 0.018485161, 0.015252535, 0.008240922, 
0.003942894, 0.002868387), D = c(176, 175, 169, 169, 169, 162, 
161, 146, 146, 143, 143, 121, 117, 90, 90, 77.7, 70.3, 69.2, 
67, 59.6, 50.4, 36.1, 33.7), E = c(0.0235, 0.044636324, 0.075155479, 
0.072909589, 0.09736484, 0.0988621, 0.199428082, 0.202422603, 
0.362878995, 0.370365297, 0.355392694, 1.438410959, 0.727212329, 
0.722221461, 1.40597032, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), F = c(69L, 
90L, 111L, 114L, 114L, 116L, 143L, 146L, 161L, 163L, 164L, 170L, 
172L, 175L, 180L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), G = c(35.29300714, 
17.47300714, 4.351007143, 3.182292857, 3.182292857, 1.411864286, 
1.435007143, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), H = c(180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 177L, 175L, 171L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), I = c(0.021, 0.0258, 0.029929032, 0.034574194, 0.064612903, 
0.088870968, 0.17816129, 0.163967742, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), J = c(67, 68.7, 75.2, 84.6, 
115, 121, 152, 155, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"H", "I", "J"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

Comment: Why don't just try to convert the Na numbers to 0? Data$A[is.na(Data$A)] = 0

Comment: Not reproducible for me. I can only think that you are running something different to the code you show above. I.e. did you compute `ylim` from the data or use `log = "xy"` at some point?

Comment: The idea is very simple. Assuming a long format, each line should have x "coordinate", y "value" and from which group it comes from. Once you have that, it's trivial to draw. In a wide format, one lines represents one x value and values for each group. Perhaps try to construct your data in one of those ways?

Comment: I selected the ylim value by hand from the excel version of the graph. Should the numbers be selected in a different way? I did not use log = "xy" for this graph. Can you clarify what you mean by "not reproducible" - Thanks!

Comment: @Casey running your code with the `dput()` output you provided I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you are looking at. I think this might help.

```
speed <- structure(list(A = c(3.59e-05, 3.75e-05, 9.67e-05, 3.92e-05,
  2.14e-05, 9.8e-05, 0.000228481, 0.000228481, 0.000415583, 0.000859052,  
0.002014948, 0.004079371, 0.00406138, 0.004353728, 0.008455587,     
0.007780939, 0.018260469, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(4.76, 6.28, 10.5,
 10.6, 12.3, 12.8, 16, 16.8, 20.7, 25.2, 34.4, 36.4, 37.7, 43.6, 48.7, 49.2,
 66.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), C = c(1.734691244, 2.016976959, 1.707373272, 
1.461511521, 0.805880184, 0.417509677, 0.427070968, 0.220364977, 0.21763318, 
0.170282028, 0.169826728, 0.095612903, 0.094247005, 0.048717051, 0.044072995, 
0.034921475,  0.023721106, 0.022901567, 0.018485161, 0.015252535, 0.008240922, 
 0.003942894, 0.002868387), D = c(176, 175, 169, 169, 169, 162, 161, 146, 146,
 143, 143, 121, 117, 90, 90, 77.7, 70.3, 69.2, 67, 59.6, 50.4, 36.1, 33.7), 
E = c(0.0235, 0.044636324, 0.075155479, 0.072909589, 0.09736484, 0.0988621, 
0.199428082, 0.202422603, 0.362878995, 0.370365297, 0.355392694, 1.438410959, 
0.727212329,  0.722221461, 1.40597032, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
F = c(69L, 90L, 111L, 114L, 114L, 116L, 143L, 146L, 161L, 163L, 164L, 170L, 
172L, 175L, 180L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), G = c(35.29300714, 
17.47300714, 4.351007143, 3.182292857, 3.182292857, 1.411864286, 1.435007143,
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA), H = c(180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 177L, 175L, 171L,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
 NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA ), I = c(0.021, 0.0258, 0.029929032, 0.034574194, 
0.064612903,   0.088870968, 0.17816129, 0.163967742, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), J = c(67, 68.7, 75.2, 84.6,  115,
 121, 152, 155, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), 
.Names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -23L))
```

**Using Base R**

Plotting

```
plot(speed$A,speed$B,xlim=range(1e-5:100),ylim=range(0:200),xlab="Time",ylab="Distance",pch=19,log="x")
points(speed$C,speed$D,col="red",pch=21)
points(speed$E,speed$F,col="blue",pch=18)
points(speed$G,speed$H,col="yellow",pch=19)
points(speed$I,speed$J,col="green",pch=20)
legend("top", legend = c("Car 1","Car 2","Car 3","Car 4","Car 5"), col = c("black","red","blue","yellow","green"),
       ncol = 2,pch=c(19,21,18,19,20))
```

The output graph is as follows:
[image]

**Option using ggplot2**
ggplot2 automatically removes the points which has missing values.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(speed,aes(A,B))+geom_point()+xlim(1e-5,100)+ylim(0,200)+scale_x_log10()+
  geom_point(data=speed,aes(C,D),col="red")+geom_point(data=speed,aes(E,F),col="blue")+
  geom_point(data=speed,aes(G,H),col="green")+geom_point(data=speed,aes(I,J),col="orange",shape=2)+
  xlab("Distance")+ylab("Distance")
```

[image]

**Yet another option using the long format data and ggplot2**

```
## Separate the data by cars
car1 <- speed[,c(1,2)]
car1$id <- "Car1"
car2 <- speed[,c(3,4)]
car2$id <- "Car2"
car3 <- speed[,c(5,6)]
car3$id <- "Car3"
car4 <- speed[,c(7,8)]
car4$id <- "Car4"
car5 <- speed[,c(9,10)]
car5$id <- "Car5"
names(car1)<- names(car2) <- names(car3) <- names(car4) <- names(car5)<- c("distance","speed","id")
```

### Combine datasets

```
myspeed <- rbind(car1,car2,car3,car4,car5)
```

### Plot ggplot with legends

```
ggplot(myspeed,aes(distance,speed))+geom_point(aes(color=id))+xlim(1e-5,100)+ylim(0,200)+scale_x_log10()
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

Comment: @DWin Thanks for your help! For now, I am trying to avoid ggplot, only because I have more experience within the other format. Any idea why car 1 data (black dots in the first graph you presented) does not show in the correct location? I tried plotting just Car 1 (A, B) and I get the same result. I tried plotting just Car 2 (C, D) and it seems like the first data set Y values get messed up. I am wondering if this is still due to the ylim value?

Comment: @DWin I did get ggplot to work btw. I will continue to use it unless I hear back feedback about the car 1 issue. My "real" data set is involves more "cars" (I used an alternate data set to simplify the presentation). I am just more familiar with the other coding.

Comment: @Jdbaba Sorry for the confusion, the ggplot does work for me. I'd rather use the Base R format because I am more familiar with it. Technically, I'm using this example to help with a similar data set of 12 "cars." If you notice on the first graph DWin provided, the data for Car 1 (black circles) do not fit the general trend of the rest of the data. The graphs from ggplot shows Car 1 data in the correct location. I was wondering why using R Base results in Car 1 data being in the incorrect position.

Comment: @ Casey: I have updated the first answer using Base R. Please check the code and output. It is working now as expected.

Comment: @Jdbaba Thank you so much! It worked on the example and on the larger data set I had. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ Casey: Thats great news. If it worked to your example and larger data set please consider accepting the answer to close this thread